# In Debreu's representation theorem of ordinal utility, is the assumption of "second countability" necessary?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, theory, decision-theory, choice-theory

[Debreu's representation theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debreu%27s_representation_theorems)

Debreu 1959 states that: second countability, continuity, and weak ordering sufficiently implies the existence of real (continuous) utility function. The second and third assumptions are also necessary.

My question is, can we prove that the second countability is not necessary by providing a counterexample?

Comment: None of the conditions besides weak ordering are necessary. A constant function on a topological space that fails to be second countable gives the desired counterexample.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I disagree. A constant utility means all points are equivalent, which induces a second countable topology!

Comment: Trivial topology is second countable!

Comment: Yes. But the underlying space need not be trivial. The topology generated by a utility function is necessarily second countable, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker You are right. My question needs to be more precise by adding some statements like "induced topology also counts"

Comment: Btw: The Wikipedia article is riddled with mistakes.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I agree. I'll find a better source